# Highlighting MySQL Data Results

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I'm going to struggle to explain this.. so please feel free to ask for more information.

I'm reading data from a MySQL DB Using :

```
SELECT * FROM resource where date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

This produces results like this :

```
ID  DATE                STACK   REF NAME        LOCATION    CREW
9   2016-01-01 06:34:50 A6YH75F 12  Local List  SPAIN       1A
8   2016-01-01 06:34:48 QWE343  23  POINT ONE   GERMANY     3A
7   2016-01-01 06:34:46 WER342  43  Insite      UK          4A
6   2016-01-01 06:34:44 WFF5G1  34  LANWise     FRANCE      5A
5   2016-01-01 06:34:42 2D3D35  21  Polent      USA         7A
4   2016-01-01 06:34:40 8541FW  33  Rosta       UK          4B
3   2015-12-30 16:48:23 A6YH75F 12  Local List  SPAIN       2A
2   2015-11-21 14:32:01 FFCWF4  34  LANWISE     FRANCE      6A
1   2015-10-14 11:02:22 POI8H6  75  BALAND      IRELAND     6B
```

This is where it's hard to explain.

I'm looping through the results and echoing out the results into a `<table>`

When this is live there may appear hundreds of entries for each NAME, what I want to do it highlight output based on some specific criteria.

**For example:**

If a NAME appears multiple times, compare the latest and previous values of STACK & REF for that name. (so comparing the last two entries per name)

If they are different highlight the output for that entry.

ie:

I can see `Local List` appears twice in the list. The first date stamp is `2016-01-01 06:34:50` & then at `2015-12-30 16:48:23`

Thats fine. On both occasions the STACK and REF are the same.

However `LANWISE` also appears twice but it's STACK is different on the newer occasion. How do I flag this and highlight the LATEST Entry for LANWISE.

I'm also looking to see if an entry hasn't appeared in the last 65 days.

So looking at the list `BALAND` last appeared `2015-10-14 11:02:22` so this is greater than 65 days and they haven't appeared since. How do I highlight this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way, but I do something like that (`$variable` is the result of your query)

```
$already = array();

#The loop where you make your table. I use foreach but use your current loop (probably while if you fetch a query response) : 
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {

    $class='';

    if(isset($already[$value['name']]) && $already[$value['name']] == $value['date']) {
        $class='highlight';
    }

#The next time, the variable exist :
    $already[$value['name']] = $value['date'];

    #do your stuf and add $class to your class in your HTML (and do something inyour CSS)
}
```

With the `isset($already[$value['name']])` you know if the line existing before. And with the `== comparator`, you know if it's the same value.

Use CSS and class HTML attribute for Highlighting the concerned lines.

Adapt this code for your usage, it's just an example based of your post.

For compare date, you can use DateTime. Example of use :

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($xDateDebut[2].'-'.$xDateDebut[1].'-'.$xDateDebut[0]);
$datetime3 = new DateTime(date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-'.date('d'));
$delaisAvantJourJ = $datetime1->diff($datetime3);
```

(`$xDateDebut` is an explosed SQL date field)

`$delaisAvantJourJ` is now an object with a lot of usefull information (like the number of day diff)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. How do I do it if the entry is greater than 65 days ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query that returns all of the information required in order to determine records that need to be highlighted:

```sql
SELECT ID, `DATE`, STACK, REF, NAME, LOCATION, CREW,
       --Calculate difference between `DATE` field and current date
       DATEDIFF(NOW(), `DATE`) AS DaysDiff,
       -- Get the count of newer records having the same NAME
       COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM resource AS r2
                 WHERE r2.NAME = r1.NAME AND r2.`Date` > r1.`Date`), 0) CountNewer,
       -- Find wether an older record exists having the same NAME and 
       -- different REF or STACK or both
       COALESCE((SELECT 1
                 FROM resource AS r3
                 WHERE r3.NAME = r1.NAME AND
                       r3.`Date` < r1.`Date` AND
                       (r3.REF <> r1.REF OR r3.STACK <> r1.STACK)), 0) IsHighlighted
FROM resource AS r1
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```